# sql group with user id and created_at time with one day interval

Tags: postgresql

```
    id  | search_id | user_id |   data   | action | activitable_id | activitable_type |         created_at         |         updated_at         
    -----+-----------+---------+----------+--------+----------------+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
     213 |         1 |       2 | ---     +| 1      |          69801 | Mention          | 2014-09-25 23:28:55.592874 | 2014-09-25 23:28:55.592874
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 54  +|        |                |                  |                            |  
         |           |         |          |        |                |                  |                            | 
     212 |         1 |       2 | ---     +| 1      |          69803 | Mention          | 2014-09-25 23:28:49.173146 | 2014-09-25 23:28:49.173146
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 73  +|        |                |                  |                            | 

     211 |         1 |       2 | ---     +| 1      |          69802 | Mention          | 2014-09-25 23:28:45.132325 | 2014-09-25 23:28:45.132325
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 73  +|        |                |                  |                            | 

     210 |         1 |       1 | ---     +| 1      |          69801 | Mention          | 2014-09-25 21:43:43.61208  | 2014-09-25 21:43:43.61208
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 73  +|        |                |                  |                            | 

     209 |         1 |       1 | ---     +| 1      |          69833 | Mention          | 2014-09-23 12:51:47.973599 | 2014-09-23 12:51:47.973599
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 54  +|        |                |                  |                            | 
     208 |         1 |       1 | ---     +| 1      |          69836 | Mention          | 2014-09-23 12:51:41.396198 | 2014-09-23 12:51:41.396198
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 54  +|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         |          |        |                |                  |                            | 
     207 |         1 |       1 | ---     +| 1      |          69832 | Mention          | 2014-09-23 12:51:36.552109 | 2014-09-23 12:51:36.552109
         |           |         | taglist:+|        |                |                  |                            | 
         |           |         | - - 66  +|        |                |                  |                                     
    (7 rows)
```

I have these user_activity table. I want to group it with user_id and created_at date with one day interval. I can group it with user_id and created_at(but without one day interval)

Comment: I don't understand this - and which RDBMS?

Comment: Please, include a sample of expected output in the question.